# What Symbol and public get [symbol]()?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm reading some Typescript code and I have a hard time understanding a line.

```
const symbol = Symbol.for('symbolname');

class Something { 

    public get [symbol]() {
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

How does exactly `get` work? Is `symbol` an argument?

Comment: Computed property (in this case method) name.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [ask]; a title like "what this means" gives almost no indication of what the question is about.

Comment: You should probably read the [docs for Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

Comment: Basically, my problem is the get definition. The array before the parenthesis confuses me. Does it create a function only for the property symbol of the array or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Symbol**

According to [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

> Every Symbol() call is guaranteed to return a unique Symbol. Every Symbol.for("key") call will always return the same Symbol for a given value of "key". When Symbol.for("key") is called, if a Symbol with the given key can be found in the global Symbol registry, that Symbol is returned. Otherwise, a new Symbol is created, added to the global Symbol registry under the given key, and returned.

Well, to make it simple, if you're familiar with `object[key]` in Javascript, you can understand `Symbol` easily.

Occasionally, we use `key` in some circumstances like below

```
const key = "keyname"
const object = {
   [key]: "value"
}
```

Now we simply convert it to symbol usage

```
const symbol = Symbol.for('symbolname');
const object = {
   [symbol]: "value" //the key is presented by a symbol
}
```

But beyond that, one outstanding feature, which we regularly use `Symbol`, is

> Symbol-keyed properties will be completely ignored when using JSON.stringify():

It's really good to serialize JSON data but ignore some fields in your code

If you want to have a better understanding of some `Symbol` features, I'd suggest you read [this article](https://fettblog.eu/symbols-in-javascript-and-typescript/)

**Getter** (in your code it's calling `get`)

According to [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) again

> The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

But firstly, we ask why we need it?

To demonstrate it, let me show you one of my favorite examples

```
class Person {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    public fullName: string; //you will assign a value for `fullName` like this `${firstName} ${lastName}`?
}
```

That `fullName` assignment will be repeated multiple times ridiculously even though you assigned values for `firstName` and `lastName`

To avoid that, we'd introduce getter

```
class Person {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
    
    //here we go with getter!
    public get fullName() {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
```

After this, you only need to assign values for `firstName` and `lastName`. And for `fullName`, you just simply call `person.fullName` which will be populated automatically!

And the last question is "Are we able to use getter with Symbol". I'd say YES!

If you check [the earlier document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#using_a_computed_property_name) for the getter, you can find this part

```
const expr = 'foo';

const obj = {
  get [expr]() { return 'bar'; }
};

console.log(obj.foo); // "bar"
```

**Conclusion**

About what you ask

```
const symbol = Symbol.for('symbolname');

class Something { 

    public get [symbol]() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Well, I guess that developer is trying to avoid unexpected data population during JSON serialization on that getter